# What could cause EF Core to search for a non existing column in a table after I removed the property?

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have just removed an unnecessary property (ProductGroup) from an object (Product) and now EF Core throws an error at me because it is searching for a column named 'ProductGroepId' the table Product.

I have removed the property from the table Product *and* from the Object Product.
Am I still missing something?

Query from stacktrace:

```
SELECT [p2].[Id], [p2].[DescriptionId],[p2].[ProductGroupId]
FROM [Product] AS [p2]
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a migration? If not add it and then update the database with Update-Database command. Make sure you have correct configurations in your Fluent Api and Relations too

Comment: Sorry but this has nothing to do with the error. All of that is fine